# C# to VB conversion for IENUMERABLE with Tuples

Tags: c#, vb.net, tuples, ienumerable

I hope I'm phrasing the question ok, pardon my lack of knowledge of if not accurately phrased and if you have a suggestion of how to better ask the question please let me know and I'll rephrase it.

I'm following this guide from Microsoft on the new Microsoft.ML package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis

The guide is built on C#, and I'm trying to convert to VB.NET. The full C# code for this guide is at: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/master/machine-learning/tutorials/SentimentAnalysis/Program.cs

I've converted everything with the exception of a few lines and I'm just lacking the knowledge on how to accomplish this conversion:

Line # 220:

```
IEnumerable<(SentimentData sentiment, SentimentPrediction prediction)> sentimentsAndPredictions = sentiments.Zip(predictedResults, (sentiment, prediction) => (sentiment, prediction));
```

Followed by lines #224 through #228:

```
foreach ((SentimentData sentiment, SentimentPrediction prediction) item in sentimentsAndPredictions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Sentiment: {item.sentiment.SentimentText} | Prediction: {(Convert.ToBoolean(item.prediction.Prediction) ? "Positive" : "Negative")} | Probability: {item.prediction.Probability} ");

            }
```

I've never worked with this before, does anyone know how to convert this code?

As a last resort, I've also tried Telerik's conversion tool at converter.telerik.com and get the following error:

```
''' Cannot convert ForEachStatementSyntax, CONVERSION ERROR: Conversion for TupleType not implemented, please report this issue in '(SentimentData sentiment, S...'
```

Comment: If you can get the C# version to compile/run, you should try a decompiler like [.NET Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/reflector/download) - Will need to check if the tool can decompile to Vb.Net though

Comment: Something like `IEnumerable(Of (Number As Integer, Text As String))` ?

Comment: Another excellent tool to use is one named "Instant VB" to convert c# to VB. Saves me tons of time. Full Disclosure: I have NO relation to the company; just a fan of their software. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out, not the neatest conversion but it works. If anyone is interested in the full code see below.

```
    Dim sentimentsAndPredictions = sentiments.Zip(predictedResults, Function(sentiment As SentimentData, prediction As SentimentPrediction) (sentiment, prediction))

    For Each item In sentimentsAndPredictions
        Dim result = item.ToTuple
        Console.WriteLine("Sentiment: " & result.Item1.SentimentText & " | Prediction: " & If(Convert.ToBoolean(result.Item2.Prediction), "Positive", "Negative"))
    Next
```

Note that in the code above, I had to pass

```
Function(sentiment As SentimentData, prediction As SentimentPrediction) (sentiment, prediction)
```

Into the Zip function, and then in the For statement convert the item into a Tuple using the .ToTuple function.

Full Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports Microsoft.Data.DataView
Imports Microsoft.ML
Imports Microsoft.ML.Data
Imports Microsoft.ML.Trainers
Imports Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text

Module Module1

    Public _dataPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "yelp_labelled.txt")
    Public _modelPath As String = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "Model.zip")

    Sub Main()

        Dim mlcontext As MLContext = New MLContext()
        Dim splitDataView As TrainCatalogBase.TrainTestData = LoadData(mlcontext)
        Dim model As ITransformer = BuildAndTrainModel(mlcontext, splitDataView.TrainSet)
        Evaluate(mlcontext, model, splitDataView.TestSet)
        UseModelWithSingleItem(mlcontext, model)

        UseLoadedModelWithBatchItems(mlcontext)

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of process ===============")

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Public Function LoadData(ByVal mlContext As MLContext) As TrainCatalogBase.TrainTestData
        Dim dataView As IDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile(Of SentimentData)(_dataPath, hasHeader:=False)
        Dim splitDataView As TrainCatalogBase.TrainTestData = mlContext.BinaryClassification.TrainTestSplit(dataView, testFraction:=0.2)
        Return splitDataView
    End Function

    Public Function BuildAndTrainModel(ByVal mlContext As MLContext, ByVal splitTrainSet As IDataView) As ITransformer
        Dim pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName:=DefaultColumnNames.Features, inputColumnName:=NameOf(SentimentData.SentimentText)).Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(numLeaves:=50, numTrees:=50, minDatapointsInLeaves:=20))
        Console.WriteLine("=============== Create and Train the Model ===============")
        Dim model = pipeline.Fit(splitTrainSet)
        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of training ===============")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Return model
    End Function

    Public Sub Evaluate(ByVal mlContext As MLContext, ByVal model As ITransformer, ByVal splitTestSet As IDataView)
        Console.WriteLine("=============== Evaluating Model accuracy with Test data===============")
        Dim predictions As IDataView = model.Transform(splitTestSet)
        Dim metrics As CalibratedBinaryClassificationMetrics = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(predictions, "Label")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Model quality metrics evaluation")
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------")
        Console.WriteLine($"Accuracy: {metrics.Accuracy}")
        Console.WriteLine($"Auc: {metrics.Auc}")
        Console.WriteLine($"F1Score: {metrics.F1Score}")
        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of model evaluation ===============")
        SaveModelAsFile(mlContext, model)
    End Sub

    Private Sub UseModelWithSingleItem(ByVal mlContext As MLContext, ByVal model As ITransformer)
        Dim predictionFunction As PredictionEngine(Of SentimentData, SentimentPrediction) = model.CreatePredictionEngine(Of SentimentData, SentimentPrediction)(mlContext)
        Dim sampleStatement As SentimentData = New SentimentData With {
            .SentimentText = "This was a very bad steak"
        }
        Dim resultprediction = predictionFunction.Predict(sampleStatement)
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("=============== Prediction Test of model with a single sample and test dataset ===============")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine($"Sentiment: {sampleStatement.SentimentText} | Prediction: {(If(Convert.ToBoolean(resultprediction.Prediction), "Positive", "Negative"))} | Probability: {resultprediction.Probability} ")
        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of Predictions ===============")
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub UseLoadedModelWithBatchItems(ByVal mlContext As MLContext)
        Dim sentiments As IEnumerable(Of SentimentData) = {New SentimentData With {
            .SentimentText = "This was a horrible meal"
        }, New SentimentData With {
            .SentimentText = "I love this spaghetti."
        }}

        Dim loadedModel As ITransformer
        Using s1 As IO.FileStream = New FileStream(_modelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            loadedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(s1)
        End Using

        Dim sentimentStreamingDataView As IDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(sentiments)
        Dim predictions As IDataView = loadedModel.Transform(sentimentStreamingDataView)
        Dim predictedResults As IEnumerable(Of SentimentPrediction) = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable(Of SentimentPrediction)(predictions, reuseRowObject:=False)
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("=============== Prediction Test of loaded model with a multiple samples ===============")

        Console.WriteLine()

        Dim sentimentsAndPredictions = sentiments.Zip(predictedResults, Function(sentiment As SentimentData, prediction As SentimentPrediction) (sentiment, prediction))

        For Each item In sentimentsAndPredictions
            Dim result = item.ToTuple
            Console.WriteLine("Sentiment: " & result.Item1.SentimentText & " | Prediction: " & If(Convert.ToBoolean(result.Item2.Prediction), "Positive", "Negative"))
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveModelAsFile(ByVal mlContext As MLContext, ByVal model As ITransformer)
        Using fs = New FileStream(_modelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
            mlContext.Model.Save(model, fs)
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("The model is saved to {0}", _modelPath)
    End Sub

End Module
```